# How can I get two random strings from two arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, random

how can I get two strings from two arrays randomly. I have something, but It doesn't pick randomly.

```
string[] firstNames = { "John", "Michael", "Victor", "Mark", "Alex", "Steven", "Zack", "Howard", "Xzavier", "Brendan", "Dustin", "Carl" };
string[] lastNames = { "Adams", "McGregor", "Piasta", "Semmel", "Laris", "Sever", "Bourque", "Percy", "Shanabarger", "Bobak", "Adair" };
string[] shuffled = firstNames.OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
string[] shuffled2 = firstNames.OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
Random firstn = new Random();
Random lastn = new Random();
int index = firstn.Next(firstNames.Length);
int index2 = lastn.Next(lastNames.Length);
Console.WriteLine($"The random name is {firstNames[index]}" + $" {lastNames[index2]}");
```

I am trying to make a random full name generator. I have tried this code multiple times and the results were: **John Adams, Victor Piasta, and so on!** And as you can see they are not random.

Comment: Try using the same instance of `Random` for both your indices.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: int index2 = firstn.Next(lastNames.Length);

Comment: @TimRutter add an answer on the question, so I can flag your answer as the best.

Answer (score 2):

Random works slightly different in .NET-Framework to .NET-Core

> In .NET Framework, the default seed value is time-dependent. In .NET Core, the default seed value is produced by the thread-static, pseudo-random number generator.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netcore-3.1#Instantiate

In the .NET-Framework only, on most Windows systems, Random objects created within 15 milliseconds of one another are likely to have identical seed values.

Use a single Random-instance on .NET-Framework to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: Does this actually answer the question OP has?

Comment: Yes, as the issue the OP has is due to the bug in .net Core over the default seed

Comment: Well, on my machine on .NET Core 3.1 there is absolutely no difference between one or two Random instances... though I agree creating a single one makes more sense.
Look at my example provided, it produces the same results with 2 different instances.

Comment: .Net Framework: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WRo34y - .Net Core: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iCWm4D

Comment: The difference between .Net Framework / .Net Core is explained in this answer.

Comment: @Purity Sounds good to me BUT you removed the mention of the bug which Luciox claims is the issue OP is dealing with. Though neither you on your machine nor dotnetfiddle.net faced this bug, since both used the default ctor. So yeah, not sure of approving, since an edit shouldn't change the meaning of the original.

Comment: Yeah, as his source explains there is no actual bug, it's just a different implementation for .NET and .NET-core. Also the undesired behaviour happens on .NET not on Core.

Mhh, I see, so it shouldn't change the original meaning even if it gives the wrong impression?

Answer (score 2):

Looks pretty random to me..

With 150 iterations you still get a performance of roughly 90 of 132 possible combinations.

Testing code:

```
HashSet<string> names = new HashSet<string>(150);

Random rndm = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
{
    names.Add($"{firstNames[rndm.Next(firstNames.Length)]} " +
              $"{lastNames[rndm.Next(lastNames.Length)]}");
}

Console.WriteLine($"{names.Count} / {firstNames.Length * lastNames.Length}");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Don't forget that true random is not possible to simulate... so you will always have some kind of repetitive distribution with higher numbers.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Just change to below so that you are using the same Random instance for both

```
int index2 = firstn.Next(lastNames.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Random` does not actually generate random numbers, but **pseudo-random** numbers. That means, you need a starting value, the so-called seed. From that value the first number is calculated. From that, one could calculate another number, and so on. These numbers look like random, but actually they are determined by the seed. If you have the same seed, you always get the same sequence of numbers.

Your `Random` class has actually a constructor where you can deliver a seed. You can try it out here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0bHDNg For the same seed, you will always get the same sequence of numbers.

If you use the constructor without a parameter, the current time is taken as the seed. This has the big advantage, that you always get a different sequence of numbers when you restart the program. But in your example, you have a problem: If the time between creating the two instances of `Random` has not changed, because the computer is so fast, they will have both the same seed and thus both the same sequence of numbers. That's why `index` and `index2` both have the same value. Just use the same instance of `Random` for generating both indices, and they don't have necessarily the same value:

```
Random random = new Random();
int index = random .Next(firstNames.Length);
int index2 = random .Next(lastNames.Length);
Console.WriteLine($"The random name is {firstNames[index]}" + $" {lastNames[index2]}");
```